# Rails paperclip uploading file outside rails app folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to use paperclip plugin to upload the file but the problem is that i have to save the uploaded file outside the rails app folder.

Tried searching it but did not help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use :path to choose where to store the images:

```
has_attached_file :photo, :path => ":rails_root/public/:class/:attachment/:id/:style_:basename.:extension"
```

Comment: have you tried changing the path to outside the :rails_root folder?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it myself (yet, but now I'm about to).  Perhaps you could place a symbolic link inside of the Rails directory that points to the location outside you want written to.